# Wait for for loop to finish before returning result

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to push 3d models into an array and return that array, however it's returning an empty array. I suspect it's because it returns the result before the for loop finishes.

```
function modelLoader(source) {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
    const allModels = []
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const model = new THREE.Group()
        model.name = source[i].name
        gltfLoader.load(source[i].file, (gltf) => {

                const children = [...gltf.scene.children]
                for (const child of children) {
                    model.add(child)
                }
                
                allModels.push(model)
            }
        )
    }
    return allModels
}
```

I've tried using async/await but I'm getting a promise and not the actual value.
Is there a way to wait for a for loop to finish before returning the result?

Comment: Probably not the core issue, but are you sure you want to call `allModels.push(model)` there and not after the load function? Hence, after it is fully loaded

Comment: That fixed the issue, I tried it now, I called allModels.push(model) right after the load function and it returns the array populated with the models. Thanks

Comment: After moving the `allModels.push(model)` to after the load function I can access the model groups and add them to the scene however I can't access the children of those groups. Using async/await solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an async workflow so `modeLoader()` will have to be async.

We have to `await` all the models being pushed. To do that we'll use `Promise.all()` with an array of promises that we'll build in the loop.

When loading each model, we'll use a `Promise` that'll `resolve` the model. That way, when all the promises are resolved, the array that's returned by `Promise.all()` will be the the array of models.

```js
async function modelLoader(source) {
  const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        const model = new THREE.Group();
        model.name = source[i].name;
        gltfLoader.load(source[i].file, (gltf) => {
          const children = [...gltf.scene.children];
          for (const child of children) {
            model.add(child);
          }
          resolve(model);
        });
      })
    );
  }
  return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: When I log the result I get a Promise, I'm fairly new to coding so if you could explain how could I then access the value from the promise?

Comment: async functions return promises, so to access an async function's return value, you need to `await` it in another async function. So the function that calls `modelLoader()` should also be async. `async function logModels(){  console.log(await modelLoader(source)) }` If you want to check the value from within `modelLoader()` then save it to a variable `const models = await Promise.all(promises)` and log it.

Comment: I saved the return value from `modelLoader()` in a variable and used `.then` in another function to access the objects in the array. I guess that achieves the same result no? Or is there any advantage using async/await?

Comment: That works. The implementation details are up to you. Async await do look a bit more concise and legible imo.